# How much do tickets costs to enter Westworld?

Tags: westworld-tv

How much does it cost to enter Westworld?

Do patrons pay for each day?

Comment: While I think the Q might benefit for an explanation in it's reasoning, I don't think it should be closed, as it pertains to class warfare themes within the series, because not everyone can afford to go to the Parks...

Comment: @DarthLocke I agree with your premise, but the fact that it wasn't made clear tells us the director (or producer) didn't find it important enough. We don't need absolute values to make those themes pungent or prevalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's $40k per day or $280k for a week. This was revealed in episode 3, according to Ben:

> Understandably, it’s not cheap. The start-up and maintenance costs for the park must be enormous, so much so that guests must pay $40,000 a day.
>
> We know this from episode three, when the sadistic (depending on your view of the Hosts’ consciousness or lack thereof) Ben is sat around the fire bored with William and Delores and declares: “I didn’t pay 40k a day for this!”

See [here](https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/tv/features/westworld-price-cost-how-much-is-a-visit-to-the-park-a7397366.html).