# Why would visitors still want to come to Westworld?

Tags: plot-explanation, westworld-tv

The plot of the 3rd [Westworld](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0475784/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0) season diverged a lot from the initial storyline of the 1st season. For instance, throughout the 3rd season, we are shown a technologically advanced human world (with cutting edge innovations in medicine and an AI capable of predicting the "destiny" of every human being). On top of that, we also heard about a nuclear attack on Paris.

So, it is fair to assume that the world presented in this TV show had gone through a lot of dire and challenging periods of time.

Given all that, based on both the technological advances that can **already** be found in the real human world (as presented by the show), and the stressful (and sometimes even painful) psychological times the people were facing, why would anyone (regardless of their income) still want to give [$40k a day](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/107354/how-much-do-tickets-costs-to-enter-westworld/107364#107364) to visit an arguably technologically not so cutting edge theme park like Westworld?

Comment: This might be out of the preview of Move & TV Stack Exchange, because it's probably going to generate primarily opinion based answers, but Westworld offered the quest a place where they could either believe they were finding themselves or be more themselves, be amused, and/or in some cases, find a business opportunity (William, Logan). Season 3 proposes that no one is really allowed to be whom they really are, because the Rehomboam controls (almost) everyone's fate and future...

Comment: For the same reason people pay money to play games, read books, eat at themed restaurants and attend swingers parties. To have fun and be allowed to do things they usually are not allowed to.

Comment: SZCZERZOKŁ and Darth Locke: Yes, I partially agree with both of these 2 views. However, your views don't even remotely address the extremely high $40k a day ticket to get a ride in the park. For instance, if guests only wanted to get "entertained" and nothing else, they could've simply just used drugs - as the ones shown in S3,E5 - which not only were enhancing multiple feelings, they were also much cheaper.

Comment: Anyone can get and use drugs (although they should not). Not many can say they had a once in a lifetime experience. The more unique the experience, the higher the cost. Just like anyone can hunt. Only the wealthy (or poachers) can hunt rare and/or dangerous animals  (although they should not). And, those that choose not to do drugs may still be thrill seekers. Hence my skydiving reference in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather narrow view of the human psyche or what others may view as enjoyable. As of today, we live in a very technologically advanced society compared to Victorian England, Medieval Europe, or Civil War America. Yet we still have people go out of their way to reenact and role-play those periods of time. People readily pay money to LARP World War I&II paintball and airsoft games. Many in our modern society will happily give up the creature comforts of advanced technology, temporarily, to go camping. What is the difference in the escapism of a twenty first century dude ranch and that of Westworld?

To go even further, people need stimuli. The more comfortable society is, the more people seek to be “on the edge”. The greater the safety of normal life, the more dangerous the hobbies become. That is why we have skydiving, bungee jumping, rock climbing, auto racing, etc.

Then, there are always going to be some in this world who actually need the thrill of having death be an actual possibility. Those are the ones that push the envelope of the above named activities and more. Or, they may be the ones who take drugs for the thrill of its taboo nature. Or they perform stunts without the proverbial “safety nets”. The people who do not want to be put in personal danger will still pay money to see others without the “safety nets”. People may not like being scared, frightened, or in danger. They do like the feeling of being scared, frightened, or in danger. Remember, the original show was about a world where there were safeties in place. But, the safeties broke.